# What is the literal for "empty size" in Qt QML?

Tags: qt, qml

The Qt documentation says about [setting the camera viewfinder resolution](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#viewfinder.resolution-prop):

> If no resolution is given or if it is empty, the backend uses a default value.

That means, there has to be a literal for the [QML basic type "size"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-size.html) encoding the value "empty". How to write that? I could not find it in the documentation, and trying `""` results in "Could not assign QString to QSize."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"-1x-1"`. It is possible to set QML properties of types "size" to that value.

This is a literal meaning "unknown or no size value". It is undocumented but I observed it when debug-printing the `Camera.viewfinder.resolution` values in situations when the resolution cannot be determined (means, while the camera is not in `CameraState.LoadedState`).

Answer (score 0):

Both `-1x-1` and `undefined` seem to work.